# Reading data in a csv after specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an excel file with multiple sheets in it and I am reading each sheet as a separate csv file.

I am able to do it but in one of the csv files created,  the data is starting from `21st line` till `20th line` there is some calculation(that i want to avoid).

Is there any method by which I can read such kind of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, can you provide a code example of what you've tried and what doesn't work about it? Also, your question isn't about `python-requests`, so you probably want to remove that tag.

Answer (score 1):

If youre reading it as a pandas DataFrame, it's very simple to do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("name_of_csv_file.csv")
df = df[20:] # Returns line 21 onwards, because it is 0 indexed
```

Edit: If 20 was set to be dynamic, you can have a function return the value

```
n_skip = get_number_of_rows_to_skip()
df = df[n_skip:]
```

Comment: That 21st line no. is not constant, in future that can be changed also. I want to read the data starting from the next line of the header (at whatsoever line it comes).

Comment: How do you identify what line the header is at?

Comment: I need to search for a keyword and that should be nothing but the name of the very fist column; so after that whatever row will come should be treated as the actual data.

Comment: So that can be done inside the function that gives you the number of rows to be skipped, and this solution would work

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute inside read_csv function called skiprows. try to skip with that.

```
usersDf = pd.read_csv('users.csv', skiprows=21)
```

Comment: That 21st line no. is not constant, in future that can be changed also. I want to read the data starting from the next line of the header (at whatsoever line it comes).

Comment: it'd be great if you can post that excel file with dummy data.

Comment: unable to post the file here  :(

Comment: okay but then you need to find some pattern in it and try to compare that first with if condition. for ex., if regular data starts with column A and ends with F but Initially it's not the case or maybe try to search after header column.